# Google Container is limiting the resource of CPU allocation despite my higher allocation

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

```
"spec": {
  "containers": [
    {
      "name": "test",
      "image": "gcr.io/helloworldnodejs-1119/mytetest",
      "resources": {
        "requests": {
          "cpu": "500m",
          "memory": "128Mi"
        }
      },
      "env": [
        {
          "name": "GET_HOSTS_FROM",
          "value": "dns"
        }
      ],
      "ports": [
        {
          "name": "middleware-server",
          "containerPort": 8000,
          "hostPort": 8000
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}


RajRajen:mytetest rajrajen$ kubectl describe pod lbmiddleware-6e1hi 
Name: lbmiddleware-6e1hi 
Namespace: default Image(s): gcr.io/helloworldnodejs-1119/mytetest 
Node: / Labels: app=mymiddleware,tier=mymiddleware 
**Status: Pending** 
Reason:
Message:
IP:
Replication Controllers: mymiddleware (1/1 replicas created) Containers: lb4btest: Image: gcr.io/helloworldnodejs-1119/mytetest

**Limits:
  cpu:        100m**

***State:      Waiting***
Ready:      False
Restart Count:  0
Events: 
FirstSeen LastSeen Count From SubobjectPath Reason Message 
Thu, 12 Nov 2015 11:05:01 -0800 Thu, 12 Nov 2015 11:05:16 -0800 5 {scheduler } ***failedScheduling Failed for reason PodFitsResources and possibly others***
```

It looks my Docker size is 130MB and even after provisioning 500MB in the POD ( GKE - container creation ) . Yet the execution sets up the Limits : cpu : 100m ..

https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/tutorials/guestbook
  instead of .YAML file, I am using middleware-controller.json to create  GKE - Google Container engine.

```
RajRajen:lb4btest rajrajen$ kubectl create -f middleware-controller.json
replicationcontrollers/lbmiddleware
```

Commands earlier used: 
`gcloud container clusters create lb4b-test-cluster --num-nodes 1 --machine-type g1-small`

This my final result of the Docker push in Google Cloud registry

```
latest: digest: sha256:3c73d0c25e65c39164258c384b34d2cab72303375c8d3f6a2e70930000b9e171 **size: 132946**
```

Answer (score 1):

You created a 1 node cluster with a relatively small machine type. By default, Google Container Engine runs cluster add-ons (logging & monitoring) that take up some of the resources in your cluster (you can disable these if you wish). It looks like you don't have enough remaining space in your cluster to launch a pod that requires this many resources. Try disabling the cluster add ons when you create the cluster or provisioning larger (or more) nodes.

Comment: Yes Robert. Without getting into details, i upgraded to n1-highcpu-2  cluster and it solved my problem. But from eConomics perspective, I need to know how much memory left in my cluster machine type (g1-small) , which is having 1.7GB overall and only 4 Redis (serv + client) each about 100mb only allocated. So, i am guessing when  we ask for g1-machine type, we have such limitation by google cloud by themself.. I don't see such limitation in the higher machine -  type cluster n1-highcpu-2 . Can you please help me finding the remaining memory available for use?

Comment: To see the currently allocated resource usage on your cluster, first run `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces` to see all of the running pods. Then for each pod run `kubectl describe pod --namespace=NAMESPACE PODNAME` and look at the "Limits" section near the bottom.

Comment: ` RajRajen:lb4btest rajrajen$ kubectl describe pod --namespace=default redis-master-hxrkp
Name:    redis-master-hxrkp
Namespace:   default
Image(s):   redis
Node:    gke-lb4b-test-cluster-39a0dff9-node-bfvq/10.240.0.3
Labels:    app=redis,role=master,tier=backend
Status:    Running
Reason:    
Message:   
IP:    10.200.0.8
Replication Controllers: redis-master (1/1 replicas created)
Containers:
  master:
    Image:  redis
    State:  Running
      Started:  Fri, 13 Nov 2015 18:01:23 -0800
    Ready:  True
    Restart Count: 0
Conditions:
  Type  Status
  Ready  True 
No events.

Comment: I am not finding the "Limits" in this higher machine - type cluster n1-highcpu-2 . Nevertheless, thanks for your time. I will try to use this if I run into an issue when I am using cluster machine type (g1-small). Thanks